# if I delete usr/bin/chattr would other components of the system be affected?

Tags: utilities, xattr

I would like to delete `chattr`, as in `/usr/bin/chattr`, I am using Linux Mint, do you think other parts of the system would be affected?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It doesn't protect you from anything, you can still make the same calls from another program...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for some reason you just want to prevent it from being used, you can just render it inoperable:

```
chmod a-x /usr/bin/chattr
```

I agree it's not a smart thing to remove the file.

Answer (score 2):

`/usr/bin/chattr` is going to be owned by a core system package (on Linux Mint, `e2fsprogs`), and your package manager is not going to be very happy when it goes. You'll probably have to perform manual intervention on each package upgrade.

I don't think removing files from core system packages is a very good idea. These kind of packages are likely assumed to exist and be intact by default.